# Amazon Redshift cache preload?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon Redshift in order to increase performance in my application, but in Redshift performance is increased only on subsequent runs.

This means I cannot get performance improvement on first run, which keeps on increasing gradually. Therefore, I have decided to run all queries at midnight in order to utilize the caching mechanism. Is there any proper way to perform cache preload? I just want to run all queries at midnight so that cache stays for the day, it can be done manually by running all pages daily but I want to automate this process. Can anyone suggest a good idea?

Tried using `jmeter` to run all the reports on a schedule basis but looking for appropriate approach.

Comment: Do your queries change throughout the day? Are these queries the only ones that will be used throughout the day? If so, it might be better to store those results elsewhere rather than having to run a Redshift cluster for the whole day. However, if these are merely a subset of queries that will be run throughout the day, then your approach is valid.

Comment: Queries itself does not change throughout the day but filter expressions are changed so storing results elsewhere is not doable. Just wanted to utilize the query compilation caching in order to achieve maximum performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **fire-up an Amazon EC2 instance each night** that runs a script that executes all the queries, then terminates. It would only be charged per-second, so it is rather low cost.

The script can use `psql` to run the queries on Redshift.

If the total run-time of the pre-warming script is under 15 minutes, you could instead run it as an **AWS Lambda function**. This could be triggered each day by an Amazon CloudWatch Event.